# node console.log how to prevent the previous text from being omitted when the text is very large？

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

### code

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var text = `...`;  // Very long, assuming 30,000 characters
console.log(text );
```

If `text` is very long, assuming there are 30000 characters, the console will omit the previous text.

Expecting results: display the previous one first, and then display a line backward when the carriage return, loop

Comment: What do you mean when you say "omitted" - if you pipe the output through `less` does it still show everything?

Comment: I don't think console.log omitted anything. Most likely your terminal application has line buffer limits. Configure your terminal with unlimited line buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you firstly add this. 
Here let obj is a object

const fs = require('fs');
then add this line where you want to add console;
fs.writeFile('./test.txt', JSON.stringify(obj));

OR
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(obj, false, null, true));
fs.writeFileSync('./test.txt', util.inspect(obj));
```

Comment: Just `util.inspect(obj)` is fine, he didn't ask 'how can I write output to a file'. He can do, `console.log(util.inspect(obj, false, null, true))`

Answer (score 0):

It's not about `nodejs`, the previous text was just truncated by the `terminal`. You can allocate more memory to your `terminal` to let it keep all the output, which is not recommended because it eats too much memory.

You can replace your `console.log` with `fs.writeFileSync('output.txt', text)`, and then in your terminal:

`vi output.txt`

to inspect the content of the text.

Once you are done and type `:q!` to quit the `vi` then the memory are released.